# IIS error page is preventing me finding an error in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, .net, exception, asp.net-web-api

I'm using ASP.NET web API. At some point an exception is being thrown before the action is being executed (possibly during DI for the controller), but I can't track it down because I just get a canned IIS error page. I have no idea how to get the Exception information.

How can I get a response with some useful information?

EDIT: I have verified that a custom ExceptionFilter will respond to exceptions thrown by a controller, but not to *this* exception which I believe is occurring before any controller code executes. Adding code to `Application_Error()` in Global.asax also doesn't respond to the Exception. The framework appears to be blind to this Exception. So that's nice.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected that. I mean I get the default IIS7.5 error page with no details about the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Check the windows event log on the server in the Application log.

Comment: Really, I'm hoping to get something useful sent as a response - for example, an HTML page with exception details.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how, and have you configured (or turned off) [custom errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx)?

Comment: I've added `<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>` in the `<system.web>` node of web.config, but to no avail.

Comment: @David: Excuse me, you've added, but .. what?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding this

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```

under the configuration node in your config file. it will inform IIS7.5 to ignore the IIS settings and pass the error along to the site.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, thank you. This prevents IIS constructing an error page. Now I just get an empty 500 response! I still have no way to trap the Exception and examine it.